# Can't place String[] object in my Queue<String[]>

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

I am getting this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

Here is the code in question.

```
final String[] methods = parseRule.getMethods();
// add to the param.
methodsToInsert.add(methods);  // <-- error from here

//Where
public String[] getMethods() {
    return new String[]{new String(parseMethod), new String(unParseMethod)};
}

//and param
Queue<String[]> methodsToInsert

//and at some point the methodsToInsert Object is
new PriorityQueue<String[]>();
```

I'm not fully sure why? Any suggestions

---

### Thanks

Wow thanks guys, I think in a previous refactoring queue was needed, but as it has evolved it is no longer required, thank you for your information and how to fix with comparators. Since PriorityQueue is no longer needed, I'll return to a List<>.

Comment: is coz I'm using add ? not put?

Comment: No, read the error message. There is a (run-time) type-restriction on what `add` accepts (for that Queue accepts), namely that they must implement Comparable.

Comment: Which implementation of `Queue` are you instantiating?

Comment: oh, and String[] doesn't have comparable ?

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError That's correct. No arrays implement Comparable.

Comment: What concrete kind of Queue is your Queue? Can you post a compilable example?

Comment: So I should change my DS from Queue, any suggestion?

Comment: new PriorityQueue<String[]>();

Comment: I have no strong need for PriorityQueue or Queue.

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError Make sure that makes it up into the question - also, do you *need* a PQ? If not, it can likely be trivially replaced.

Comment: if u r using Queue of util pkg thn i dnt thnk it will show any error

Comment: You need to read the javadoc for PriorityQueue then: "A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException)."

Comment: You can use the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29) that takes a `Comparator`; you'll need to write a `String[]` Comparator.

Comment: THANKS GUYS, I really balls up there. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `PriorityQueue` must order its elements somehow, either accepting a `Comparator` in its constructor, or relying on its elements being `Comparable`.

From [`PriorityQueue` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. A priority queue does not permit null elements. A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).

You haven't supplied a `Comparator`, so it expects all elements added to be `Comparable`, but arrays aren't `Comparable`.

Supply your own `Comparator<String[]>` using [the `PriorityQueue` constructor that takes a `Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) makes it clear:

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. A priority queue does not permit `null` elements. A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in `ClassCastException`).

You should pass a `Comparator<String[]>` instance to the [appropriate constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29) of `PriorityQueue` that will be used for comparison, as `String[]` can't be compared on natural ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) contains elements that are "ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time." Although Sting objects have a natural ordering, arrays of string do not. You will need to provide a Comparator object at the time you create the queue object which can say that one array of String is greater or less than another array of String.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a `String[]` to a `PriorityQueue` because a `String[]` is not `Comparable`. The solution depends on what you really need to accomplish.

**Queue the Strings**

Use Queue's `addAll()` method.

**Queue the Strings and Retain Grouping**

Queue your `String[]` objects in a `Queue`.

**Queue the String and Retain Priority**

Use PriorityQueue's `addAll()` method.

**Queue the Strings, Retain Grouping, and Retain Priority**

Wrap your `String[]` in a new class. Apply the Comparable interface. Implement the `compareTo()` and `equals()` methods. Queue your custom objects in a `PriorityQueue`.